# linux + tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: linux, terminal, environment-variables, colors, tput

I use in my bash script the tput command in order to colored the text

as

```
tput setaf 2
```

when I run the script from putty or console every thing is ok

but when I run some external WIN application engine that run the script via SSH
the we get the following error on tput

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

please advice what need to set ( ENV or else ) in my bash script in order to use the tput command ?

Comment: You need to set $TERM to whatever terminal emulator that application is compatible with.

Comment: can you show me please example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When connecting via `ssh`, environment variables may (or may not) be passed to the remote application.  Also a *"WIN application engine"* could very well not set `TERM` at all.

If `TERM` is `putty` (or `xterm`, for that matter), these have the same effect:

```
tput setaf 2
tput -T putty setaf 2
```

since the control sequences used for `setaf` are the same.  Likewise, if `TERM` is `linux`, these are the same

```
tput setaf 2
tput -T linux setaf 2
```

The `setaf` is used for setting the foreground (text) to a particular value using *ANSI* (x3.64) escape sequences.  Most of the terminals you are using do that — or some do not recognize any of those escape sequences.  Since the application was not mentioned, you will have to experiment to see if the *"WIN application engine"* recognizes those escape sequences.  If it does, it probably uses the same *ANSI* escapes, so you could just do

```
tput -T xterm setaf 2
```

(There are other differences between putty, linux and xterm, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of possible options.

1. Don't use `tput` unless you've an interactive terminal session. You could choose either of these approaches:

   ```
   [[ -t 1 ]] && tput setaf 2 ...          # Only set a colour if we have a tty

   [[ -n "$TERM" ]] && tput setaf 2 ...    # Only set a colour if we have a terminal type definition
   ```
2. Set a dummy terminal type. You can `export TERM=dumb` to disable most features of `terminfo`/`termcap`. Obviously you would want to execute this only if the terminal type was not already set:

   ```
   [[ -z "$TERM" ]] && export TERM=dumb    # Set a dummy terminal type if none set

   [[ ! -t 1 ]] && export TERM=dumb        # Set a dummy terminal type unless a tty
   ```

   With this approach you don't need to change any subsequent code; you could even set it before running your application and it wouldn't need to know any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use tty command to identify if your script is being executed from a terminal or remotely:

```bash
if tty -s
then 
    # executed only if in a terminal
    tput setaf 2 
fi
```

The command between `then` and `fi` will not be executed while you specify a command in an SSH session.

Comment: On BSD-ish systems, [man 1 tty](https://man.openbsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=tty) says to use `[ -t 0 ]` instead of `tty -s`. As this uses a shell builtin it is also more robust and efficient.

Comment: That link is now broken, it has moved to https://man.openbsd.org/tty.1

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for the tput problem:

```
# when $TERM is empty (non-interactive shell), then expand tput with '-T xterm-256color'
[[ ${TERM}=="" ]] && TPUTTERM='-T xterm-256color' \
                  || TPUTTERM=''

declare -r    RES='tput${TPUTTERM} sgr0'       REV='tput${TPUTTERM} rev'
declare -r    fRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 1'    bRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 1'
declare -r    fGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 2'    bGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 2'
...
echo ${fRD}" RED Message: ${REV} This message is RED REVERSE. "${RES}
echo ${fGN}" GREEN Message: ${REV} This message is GREEN REVERSE. "${RES}
...
```

that way it makes no sense if there's an interactive or a non-interactive shell - tput still works fine.